# Angular 8 Multiple layout use different css and js for each layout

Tags: angular, angular8

I am working on an application which include frontend site layout and backend admin layout. These both layouts have different CSS and JS. How can use different CSS and Js according to each layout template. Here is my structure.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Couaff</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://explorercanvas.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/excanvas.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- **Favicon** -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!-- **CSS - stylesheets** -->
    <link id="default-css" href="assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="assets/css/shortcode.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- **Additional - stylesheets** -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link href="assets/css/animations.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link id="skin-css" href="assets/skins/red/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/meanmenu.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/pace-theme-loading-bar.css">

    <!-- **Font Awesome** -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- **Google - Fonts** -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,300,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="assets/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>


  <!-- **jQuery** -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.sticky.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.inview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jsplugins.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.meanmenu.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My app.routing.ts is consists of the following code.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SiteLayoutComponent } from './layouts/site-layout/site-layout.component';
import { HomeComponentComponent } from './other-component/home-component/home-component.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from './secure-component/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {AdminLayoutComponent} from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
      path: '', component : SiteLayoutComponent,
        children: [
          {path: 'home', component: HomeComponentComponent}
        ]
    },
    {
      path: '', component : AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [
          {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}

        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My point is here to just load different style sheets and js files for each layouts I created. Here is both layouts

[image: application structure]

> Note: I don't want to use multiple application inside one angular 8
>   application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use routing for choosing which layout to use on specific url.
Your layout should use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'a',
    component: LayoutAComponent,
    children: [{ path: '', component: ContentComponent },]
  },
  {
    path: 'b',
    component: LayoutBComponent,
    children: [{ path: '', component: ContentComponent },]
  },
]
```

You can check this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-layouting). If thats not enough you may want to create lazy loaded modules to separate stuff loaded by each view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer please review update question. My question is to load different style sheets and js files for different these two layouts. As I have different css and js files for front end site layout and different css and files for admin site layout.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked by user

Comment: @Zakirhussain question has been modified after my answer

Answer (score 0):

For each module l, what i would try to do is import the css files in the scss file using @import and pointing it to the css i want it to use and likewise for the jquery, i would import it as a file in the component.ts file . Check https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-shortcut-to-importing-styles-files-in-components for further explanation